# Cant figure out this invalid syntax error (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

Hey i've been trying to write some stuff for my university projects, right now everything should be working but i keep getting the INVALID SYNTAX error on Line "elif menu==4:" (i'll mark it with \), i can figure out what i'm doing wrong, any help is really appreciated

````
1)The last digit of a natural number
2)The fraction of a positive number
3)The number of tens inside of a natural number
4)The sum of a 3 digit number
""")
menu=float(input('Please make a selection'))

if menu==1:
    print('Input a Natural number')

    A0 = float(input("input the last digit"))
    A1 = float(input("input the second digit"))
    A2 = float(input("the the third digit"))
    A3 = float(input("the fourth digit"))
    A4 = float(input("any remaning digits"))
    print (A0)

elif menu==2:

   Frac = float(input('Please input the fraction of your number'))

   num = float (input('please input the main body of the nymber'))
   if num < 0:
        print('The number is too low or incorrect please try again.')

        print ('the main part of the number is',(num))
        print ('the fraction of your number is',(Frac))



elif menu==3:
    Num = float(input('Please input a Natural number'))
    if Num < 0:
     print('The number is too low or incorrect please try again.')

print(Num % 10)

\\the line below gets the error.

elif menu==4:

    print ('Please Input a 3 digit number (this program will not work with a longer number)')
    A0 = float(input("input the last digit"))
    A1 = float(input("input the second digit"))
    A2 = float(input("the the third digit"))
    print(A0+A1+A2)```
````

Comment: print(Num % 10) is not indented the way it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the print statement right before your error.

```
print(Num % 10)
```

Remove that and it should work.

The elif statements must be consecutive and the print statement interrupts that and causes the invalid syntax.

Comment: thanks that was the solution, but instead of deleting that part i just figured out it was not a part of the last elif statement, so i uhh. pressed tab and that fixed it.